# Recursive loop unpacking too many values in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I try to display a dict, which depth is unknown and represents a file tree, with a recursive loop. This is my simple example data:

```
{
   "smartphone":{
      "upload_1693308862":{
         "image1.png":{
            "url":"<url comes here>"
         },
         "image2.png":{
            "url":"<url comes here>"
         },
         "image3.png":{
            "url":"<url comes here>"
         },
         "image4.png":{
            "url":"<url comes here>"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And this is my jinja code:

```
{%- for level, subdict in file_structure.items() recursive %}
    <li>
    {%- if level.url -%}
        <a href="{{ level.url }}">{{ level }}</a>

    {% elif subdict is iterable and subdict is not string  %}
        {{ level }}
        <ul class="submenu">{{ loop(subdict) }}</ul>
    {% else %}
        {{ level }}
    {% endif %}

    </li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

The exception I get is this one:

```
2023-08-29T14:25:56.480784300Z     {%- for level, subdict in file_structure.items() recursive %}
2023-08-29T14:25:56.480785800Z ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Shouldn't `items()` always return exactly two values? What's wrong here?

Comment: Is your example data an exact reproduction of `{{ file_structure | pprint }}`?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes (except the URLs of course)

Comment: It looks like this is due to the `recursive` marker

Comment: ^-- So the trick, in your case, is to do `<ul class="submenu">{{ loop(subdict.items()) }}</ul>`

Comment: Worked, thanks, add it as answer please